# Render Problem - Android Studio is not rendering the layout

Tags: dji-sdk

Android Studio is not rendering the layout in activity_main.xml. I can't edit the app wihtout the visual rendering. Just to be clear, I'm not talking about the emulator, this is just the layout.

**Android Studio: 4.2.2,
Android SDK: 28-30,
DJI UXSDK: 4.14,
DJI SDK: 4.14**

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Constructor must call super() or this() before return
Exception Details:
  Location:
    dji/common/bus/UXSDKEventBus.<init>()V @0: return
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0000000: b12a b700 10b1                         

    at dji.ux.widget.FPVWidget.addSubscriptions()
    at dji.ux.widget.FPVWidget.onAttachedToWindow()
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20479)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:332)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:369)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:710)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:865)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:174)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```